# Layout - How to dynamically add views and break line based on empty space

Tags: android

I would like to have a Layout for Views in Android that manages itself to use its empty space dynamically and EITHER puts the next view added right to the last view if it still fits OR breaks line and adds the view on the new line on the left...

Example:

```
||Name|LoooooongName|Ho      ||
||SuperLongName|NextLongname ||
||Bob|Sue|Martin|Richard|Joe ||
||Marvin|Homer|Ann-Marie     ||
```

Any clues? Thanks for your help!

Comment: just write a custom layout that do this

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but not easy. You will have to create a custom layout. Check out the source code to [LinearLayout](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/LinearLayout.java) for an example, specifically layoutHorizontal().

You will override ViewGroup.onLayout(). Inside it you will check the size of your children using View.getMeasured{Width,Height}(), making sure they can fit on the line or move to the next.

Comment: Puh, so there is really the need to write a whole Layout on one's own? Can't imagine that does not exits already...